# How to calculate vibrational spectra of organic molecules?

Tags: computational-chemistry, spectroscopy, spectrophotometry

I watched a ted talk ([Luca Turin: The science of scent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzOcvINn8Iw)) and was wondering if anyone had any examples of how to calculate vibrational spectra of molecules (used as fragrances)?  Would love to figure out how he computed these charts.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Going off this definition: A molecule is formed when two or more atoms join together chemically. A compound is a molecule that contains at least two different elements. All compounds are molecules but not all molecules are compounds. I would like to start with the easiest which looks like molecules and go towards compounds.

Answer (score 4):

The usual approach is:

- Find the equilibrium geometry (within the Born-Oppenheimer app.).
- Expand the energy in Taylor series till second order term. The first order will be 0 because of the minimum energy condition.
- Include this expression in the Hamiltonian.
- Generate a coordinate transformation to get normal coordinates.
- Relate second order derivative of the potential energy with the force constant of Hook law (Using second order term we can identify it with a harmonic oscillator). Then get the harmonic frequencies.
- The software employed should give also the intensity for each frequency.
- Plot intensity vs. frequency/energy/wave length. You'll get only "points". To transform them to a continuous function you can use a Lorentzian like function.

Details can be found in most computational quantum chemistry books.

Answer (score 4):

You can build molecules and calculate vibrational frequencies with [Molcalc](http://molcalc.org).  Molcalc does have a molecular size limit, so for bigger molecules you must download some programs.  I have written about [computing vibrations with the GAMESS program](http://molecularmodelingbasics.blogspot.dk/search/label/vibration).